# Unable to link "react-native-background-timer" package for android even after manual link

Tags: android, reactjs, mobile, native

```
rootProject.name = 'Pomodora'

**include ':react-native-background-timer'
project(':react-native-background-timer').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-background-timer/android')**

apply from: new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('expo/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../scripts/autolinking.gradle");
useExpoModules()

apply from: new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../native_modules.gradle");
applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)

include ':app'
includeBuild(new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('react-native-gradle-plugin/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim()).getParentFile())

if (settings.hasProperty("newArchEnabled") && settings.newArchEnabled == "true") {
  include(":ReactAndroid")
  project(":ReactAndroid").projectDir = new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../ReactAndroid");
  include(":ReactAndroid:hermes-engine")
  project(":ReactAndroid:hermes-engine").projectDir = new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../ReactAndroid/hermes-engine");
  include(":react-native-background-timer")
  project(":react-native-background-timer").projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-background-timer/android');
}
```

```
package com.fellipeutaka.pomodora;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.config.ReactFeatureFlags;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import com.fellipeutaka.pomodora.newarchitecture.MainApplicationReactNativeHost;

import expo.modules.ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher;
import expo.modules.ReactNativeHostWrapper;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.List;

**import com.ocetnik.timer.BackgroundTimerPackage;**

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {
  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHostWrapper(
    this,
    new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
      List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
      // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
      **packages.add(new BackgroundTimerPackage());**
      return packages;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }
  });

  private final ReactNativeHost mNewArchitectureNativeHost =
      new ReactNativeHostWrapper(this, new MainApplicationReactNativeHost(this));

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    if (BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED) {
      return mNewArchitectureNativeHost;
    } else {
      return mReactNativeHost;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we enable the TurboModule system
    ReactFeatureFlags.useTurboModules = BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED;
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);

    initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
    ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.onApplicationCreate(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onConfigurationChanged(@NonNull Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.onConfigurationChanged(this, newConfig);
  }

  /**
   * Loads Flipper in React Native templates. Call this in the onCreate method with something like
   * initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
   *
   * @param context
   * @param reactInstanceManager
   */
  private static void initializeFlipper(
      Context context, ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      try {
        /*
         We use reflection here to pick up the class that initializes Flipper,
        since Flipper library is not available in release mode
        */
        Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("com.fellipeutaka.pomodora.ReactNativeFlipper");
        aClass
            .getMethod("initializeFlipper", Context.class, ReactInstanceManager.class)
            .invoke(null, context, reactInstanceManager);
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])

    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    def isGifEnabled = (findProperty('expo.gif.enabled') ?: "") == "true";
    def isWebpEnabled = (findProperty('expo.webp.enabled') ?: "") == "true";
    def isWebpAnimatedEnabled = (findProperty('expo.webp.animated') ?: "") == "true";
    def frescoVersion = rootProject.ext.frescoVersion

    // If your app supports Android versions before Ice Cream Sandwich (API level 14)
    if (isGifEnabled || isWebpEnabled) {
        implementation "com.facebook.fresco:fresco:${frescoVersion}"
        implementation "com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-okhttp3:${frescoVersion}"
    }

    if (isGifEnabled) {
        // For animated gif support
        implementation "com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:${frescoVersion}"
    }

    if (isWebpEnabled) {
        // For webp support
        implementation "com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:${frescoVersion}"
        if (isWebpAnimatedEnabled) {
            // Animated webp support
            implementation "com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:${frescoVersion}"
        }
    }

    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    if (enableHermes) {
        //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-engine:+") { // From node_modules
            exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
        }
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }

    **implementation project(':react-native-background-timer')**
}
```

These are all of the changes that I was supposed to make.

I've done all of the necessary steps listed in the repo. It's still not working.

Android: TypeError: Cannot read property 'setTimeout' of undefined or TypeError: null is not an object

I tried making sure all of the version were compatible, and even restarted the project.

Comment: Have you considered migrating your RN project to Expo to avoid having to futz around with all the "native bits"?